# Bootstrap prevent dropdown from disappearing on cursor move

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `navbar` with logo on left and a `navbar-right` (`float: right`) on the far right which contains a `dropdown` as the first element and some other elements. The dropdown menu is large and responsive.

What I'd like to be able to do is prevent the dropdown from disappearing when I hover over the dropdown and move the cursor left in navbar (towards the logo). The dropdown should remain open as long as the cursor is still in the navbar. So this should not happen -

[image]

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gva90uks/10/embedded/result/

Code - http://jsfiddle.net/gva90uks/10/

I've tried adding `left-padding` to the `dropdown-menu` when the menu is `open`, but the padding has to be dynamic based on window size otherwise it pushes the logo. So I'm looking for better solutions rather than adding the padding.

I'm okay with both js and css based solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `flexbox` and `flex-grow`, like below.

This because `flexbox` allows elements to grow bigger (or shrink smaller) if there is space. So the drop-down link (the parent `<li>`-element) will at default styling be the width of the text on the link But when we hover over the link, the `<li>`-element will grow as much as possible, i.e. all the way to the `brand`, causing the drop-down not to hide when hovering over the top bar (which now contains the much bigger `<li>` (dropdown) element).

```css
.navbar .container-fluid {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .container-fluid .navbar-collapse {
  flex-grow:2;
  
}

.mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*padding: 27px 0;*/
}

.navbar-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu-area {
  display: flex;
}

#menu-area .dropdown-toggle {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover + .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.menu-large:hover {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
 
.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown menu-large">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu mega-menu">
            <div class ="container">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is clever but the `hover` has to stay on the `dropdown`. It can't be applied to the entire `navbar-collapse` because the `navbar` can have other elements as well.

Comment: I would `justify-content: flex-end;` rather than reversing the list order and using `flex-direction: row-reverse;`, but other than that, perfect!

Comment: I think it'll be helpful to other people if you add a bit of explanation to your answer. Also you can remove the old suggestion since it'll be preserved in the history. :)

Comment: @aandis Yeah, that makes much more sense (blaming I was tired...) I updated the answer as you suggested. I'm still quite new at answering questions here, thanks for the directions! :)